# Want to convert Decimal from signed 2's complement to hexdecimal without signed 2's complement (ex : -73 -> B7)

Tags: java, hex, iot, gprs

i am receving sensor data which sends me Decimal from signed 2's complement want to convert it to hex decimal without signed 2's complement

Comment: And what did you find/write already to achieve that goal? Because SO is here to help you solve problems with your code, it's not a general help forum for when you have an idea but haven't done anything about it yet. Give [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) a read-through, and then update your post accordingly.

Comment: Most things in this question make no sense to me, or are impossible. Maybe I'm wrong, but I expect that the sensor *doesn't* send data in decimal (a common cause for this confusion is that integers are printed in decimal by default, but that doesn't mean that the integer *is* decimal, it's just printed that way), but send data as a raw signed byte (which you can print in hexadecimal). Please clarify.

Comment: yes you are right its sends in byte but there is a default file provided by sensor manufacturer so thats decode the bytes and gives me Decimal from signed 2's complement

Comment: Do you have to use that default file? It's still possible to convert from a decimal representation, but that's an avoidable extra step

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
String decimal = "-73";
int number = Integer.parseInt(decimal);
String unsignedHex = String.format("%02X", number & 0xff);
```

The `parseInt` call converts the signed decimal string to a (signed) `int` value.

The `format` call converts the `int` to an unsigned byte string in uppercase hexadecimal:

- The `number & 0xff` expression strips off the sign extension.
- The `"%02X"` format says uppercase hexadecimal (`X`) in a 2 character field.  The `0` means zero padded.  Read [Format String Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more information.